# Verify if rewrite module is installed and activated

Tags: docker, apache, suitecrm

I have SuiteCRM running in docker container. I am trying to call the SuiteCRM authentication API endpoint through postman but I get a 404 error. (http://localhost/Api/access_token)

I am refering to SuiteCRM document to connect to the endpoints( https://docs.suitecrm.com/developer/api/developer-setup-guide/json-api/)

But, I am stuck on this step where I have to enable mod_rewrite on apache server. I am also not sure in which file I have to change the AllowOverride directive. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4zFv.png)